# How to disable a button once clicked in JSX, ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm making a 2 player tic tac toe game and I can not find out how to prevent a player from clicking on a square that has already been clicked on.

Currently if a player clicks on a X/O already present it changes the state to O/X . I want to disable that.

**Board.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Square from './Square'

export default function Board () {

  const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill());

  const renderSquare = (i) => {
    return <Square 
      squares={squares[i]} 
      handleClick={()=>handleClick(i)}
    />;
  }

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    const newSquares = squares.slice();
    newSquares[i] = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    setSquares(newSquares);
    setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
  }

  const status = 'Next player: ' + (xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(0)}
        {renderSquare(1)}
        {renderSquare(2)}
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(3)}
        {renderSquare(4)}
        {renderSquare(5)}
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(6)}
        {renderSquare(7)}
        {renderSquare(8)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Square.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Square ({ squares, handleClick, disabled })  {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={()=>handleClick()} disabled={disabled}>
      {squares}
    </button>
  );
}
```

I've used state to prevent clicking on a button already pressed, but it disables all the button in the game rather than just the one that was pressed.

Comment: This is slightly off topic so I'll only jot down a FYI comment. Generally speaking, disabling a button in this manner does not align with the best accessibility practices. It may cause screen reader users especially to lose their focus on the page which makes ensuing navigation difficult. I understand that this may not be pertinent in your case, but it can be relevant to other people accessing this question. Instead of disabling the button you could consider ignoring the click handler on an already selected square and using some visual styling to mark the square as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `disabled` prop to your `Square` with a value based on if the square has data or not, e.g.

```
const renderSquare = (i) => {
    return <Square 
      squares={squares[i]} 
      handleClick={()=>handleClick(i)}
      disabled={!!squares[i]}
    />;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually solved it.
Btw what does the double exclamation mark ( !! ) mean ?

Comment: `!!` is two copies of `!`, which is the not operator. Basically, `!!` is being used to convert the value to a boolean. So another way to do it would be `disabled={Boolean(squares[i])}`